# Tabs and subTabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a page with ParentTabs and ChildTabs, now on ParentTabs are displayed childTabs with other content each. How can I do that action button (continue) to go to the next child tab in order to display the other content tab.

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="tineUl">
            <ul class="mainUl">
                <li class="selected"><a><span>TabOne</span></a></li>
                <li><a><span>TabTwo</span></a></li>
                <li><a><span>ThirdTab</span></a></li>
                <li><a><span>FourthTab </span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="subContent">
            <div class="tineUl">
                <ul class="subMainUl">
                    <li class="selected"><a><span>TabOne</span></a></li>
                    <li><a><span>TabTwo</span></a></li>
                    <li><a><span>ThirdTab</span></a></li>
                    <li><a><span>FourthTab </span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="subContentChild">
                <p>
                   SubContent Menu Zone.
                </p>
         <input type="submit" class="button" value="Cancel"></input>
         <input type="submit" class="button" value="Continue"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/138/**

Comment: there is no js in the jsfiddle. can you fill in what you have tried till now?

Comment: I don't have any .js, this is what I;m looking for.

Comment: You currently only have a single content tab. Visually switching between tabs is as simple as assigning the selected class to the appropriate `li`. However, you will propaply need an ajax call to fetch the new sub-content and insert it into the `subContentChild` div. Or if you load all sub content up front, switch visibility similar as you would with the `li` tags. Have a look at the jQuery API documentation for details on selectors in general, toggleclass(), jQueryUI, switchClass() or even look at jQueryTabs. http://jqueryui.com/ http://api.jquery.com/ http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#twitter-contact choose your tabs .